# where句で絞ったselect結果を横に結合する方法

Tags: sql, sqlite

下記、２つのテーブルがあります。

ユーザ一覧
[image: ユーザー一覧]

ユーザー属性
[image: attribute]

2つのテーブルを結合して
<ユーザ属性のname=day,value=0501>
かつ
<ユーザ属性のname=team,value=sales>
の条件でselectした結果を
下記のように出力したいのですが、上手くいきません。

求める結果
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

試したsqlと結果はこちらです。

```sql
select
a.username,
case when b.name='day' then b.value end as 'day',
case when b.name='team' then b.value end as 'team'
from user_entity as a
inner join user_attribute as b
on a.user_id = b.user_id
where case when b.name='day' then b.value = '0501' 
when b.name='team' then b.value = 'sales' 
end
```

結果
usernameが重複してしまっているのと、dayとteamの条件がAND条件ではなくOR条件になってしまっています。(satoとyamadaも出てしまう）

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

もし分かる方いらっしゃいましたら、よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

確認していませんが、これぐらいでどうでしょうか？

```
SELECT username, '0501' AS day, 'sales' AS team
FROM user_entity AS ue
INNER JOIN user_attribute AS ua1 ON ue.user_id = ua1.user_id AND ua1.name = 'day' AND ua1.value = '0501'
INNER JOIN user_attribute AS ua2 ON ue.user_id = ua2.user_id AND ua2.name = 'team' AND ua2.value = 'sales'
```

> <ユーザ属性のname=day,value=0501>
> かつ
> <ユーザ属性のname=team,value=sales>
> の条件

とのことなので、`day`カラムは`0501`であり`team`カラムは`sales`なのは自明で、即値でいいかなと。結局クエリで取得したいのは`username`だけだと思いました。

Comment: こちら、実行してみましたが結果0件でした。
また、質問するにあたりかなり省略してしまったのですが、dayとteamは固定ではなく、dayは0501以降は

Comment: @ema すみません、コピペミスで一番最後が`ua2.value`になるべきところが`ua1.value`と誤っていました。修正しましたのでこれで動くはずです。

Comment: 修正ありがとうございます！実行結果はまさに求めたものでした。
また、実際には'0501'と'sales'固定で入れたくなかったので、下記のように修正することで対応できました。

```
SELECT username, ua1.value AS day, ua2.value AS team
FROM user_entity AS ue
INNER JOIN user_attribute 
AS ua1 ON ue.user_id = ua1.user_id
AND ua1.name = 'day' AND ua1.value = '0501'
INNER JOIN user_attribute 
AS ua2 ON ue.user_id = ua2.user_id 
AND ua2.name = 'team' AND ua2.value = 'sales'
```

INNER JOIN ON の中でANDが使えるのを知らず、勉強になりました。